# Correct "base path" terminology

Tags: url, path, terminology, definition, convention

Consider a website installed in the 'mysite' directory:

`/var/www/html/mysite/index.php`
document root = `/var/www/html`
url = `www.mysite.com/mysite/index.php`

What would you call the following:

1. **/var/www/html/mysite/** index.php (Base path? Root path?)
2. /var/www/html **/mysite** /index.php -or- www.mysite.com **/mysite** /index.php (Path? Base path?)
3. **www.mysite.com/mysite**/index.php (Base URL)

I can't seem to come up with a clear cut name to distinguish 1 and 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm from a ruby-on-rails background but...

1) either base-path or root path are used for this. Pick one and be consistent :)
3) in RoR we call this the "root url" but it's also kinda the "home path" too.
as to 2 - it doesn't occur in rails (or at least we don't have a name for it)

it sounds like the following would be consistent without confusing them all:

1. base-filepath == **/var/www/html/mysite/** /index.php
2. root-filepath == /var/www/html **/mysite** /index.php
3. root-url      == **www.mysite.com/mysite**/index.php

An alternative would be:

1. root-filepath
2. home-filepath
3. home-url

my 2c :)

Comment: Thanks for the RoR perspective- I'm realizing there is indeed no canonical standard, and every system platform has its own variations on the names. I'll give you the answer as it's a valid answer out of many. (See my answer for more...)

Answer (score -3):

Turns out these can be referred to in a variety of ways. I'll list them here as I find them:

**In [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects):**

2 = script_prefix